# How to Hide/Show button in android home screen widget

Tags: android, user-interface, widget, onclick

I am a beginner of android development. Current, I am working on creating a small home screen widget that is changing wallpaper of the mobile on click the button. The setting wallpaper is working fine but I want to make a clickable small picture (ImageView) to allow user to show and hide this setting button.

I setup it on service and use PendingIntent in order to attach my onClick event to the same service, but I cannot detect the property of button whether showing or hiding.

Therefore,is there any suggestion and solution to make my ImageView to show or hide the button in home screen widget?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use mButton.setVisibility(View.GONE) to hide the button.

You can also check state of button's visibility in a boolean variable using mButton.isShown().

Edited:

For Example

In `onReceive()` of `AppWidgetProvider`,

```
     remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.yourwidgetlayout );

     remoteViews.setViewVisibility(viewId, visibility);
```

So for hiding your Button

```
     remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonId,View.INVISIBLE);
```

**Edit - 2:**   According to Kartik's comment,

Sample Code:

```
    public class ButtonHideShowWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

     private static boolean status = false;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      super.onReceive(context, intent);
      if (intent.getAction()==null) {

             Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
             if(extras!=null) {

                 remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.your_widget_layout );
                 if(status){
                   remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonId,View.INVISIBLE);
                  status = false;
                 }else{
                   remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonId,View.VISIBLE);
                  status = true;
              }

                 watchWidget = new ComponentName( context, ButtonHideShowWidget.class );

                 (AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)).updateAppWidget( watchWidget, remoteViews );
                 //Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked "+status, 2000).show();
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also think about it but I don't know how to call it through RemoteView

Comment: Can we check the current visibility state of button? It seems like remoteViews doesn't allow to getViewVisibility. Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: you have to maintain a static boolean flag for handling whether your button is invisible or not. Save the state of your button in flag and for maintaining clicks you can build logic in remoteView method.

Comment: @Hiral i want to open activity when click on homescreen widget how can i will get help me?

Answer (score 1):

Call setVisibility(View.Invisible); with the help of button object created by you after the user clicks the button.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how can i access that button object from RemoteView?

Comment: I also not having the knowledge of remote view but let me try it or study something related to it then I'll tell you the real solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
// To remove button
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

// To transparent button
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing this in onReceive(Context, Intent) method as mentioned in official documentation

> This is called for every broadcast and before each of the above callback methods. You normally don't need to implement this method because the default AppWidgetProvider implementation filters all App Widget broadcasts and calls the above methods as appropriate.

You should do this in onAppWidgetOptionsChanged().
See the [official docs.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Showing extends AppWidgetProvider {

     private static boolean status = false;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      super.onReceive(context, intent);
      if (intent.getAction()==null) {
             Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
             if(extras!=null) {
                 remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.your_widget_layout );
                 if(status){
                   remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonId,View.INVISIBLE);
                  status = false;
                 }else{
                   remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonId,View.VISIBLE);
                  status = true;
                }
                 watchWidget = new ComponentName( context, ButtonHideShowWidget.class );
                 (AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)).updateAppWidget( watchWidget, remoteViews );
                 //Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked "+status, 2000).show();
             }
          }
       }
    }
```